# Difference in Difference and Selection Into Treatment

Tags: fixed-effects-model, difference-in-difference, selection-bias

Suppose I impose that the true model of some variable of interest is:

$$
Y_{it} = \alpha_i + \beta_t+\tau_{it}D_{it}+\epsilon_{it}
$$

Where $ D_{it} = 1\{E_i \geq t\} $. This is a kind of DID model where you can see that there is treatment effect heterogeneity. Suppose further than I know that the treatment assignment does not depend on the random shocks such that:

$$ E[D_{it}|\epsilon_{it}, \alpha_i, \beta_t, X] = E[D_{it}| \alpha_i, \beta_t, X] $$

I believe that I am asking something stupid here, but is there a way to get from this assumption to the following?:

$$
E[\epsilon_{it}|D_{it}, \alpha_i, \beta_t, X] = E[\epsilon_{it}| \alpha_i, \beta_t, X] 
$$

The latter, of course, is very standard. The reason I ask this question is that the former assumption is implied if treatment timing is randomised which should be enough for DID, but I don't see it here. Perhaps mean independence of treatment assignment is not sufficiently strong?